# How can I find my app and the SQLite .db file in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, directory-structure

I created my first Android App with `SQLite` and tested it on my phone.
Now I installed an `SQLiteManager` on the phone and I would like to open the `SQLitedatabse` file.

The location is `/data/user/0/com.<appname>/database/database.db`
But this folder does not exist. How can I find and access the `database` file?
And I am also not able to find the apk of my App. In `Android/data/` I can see all other installed apps, but not my own app.

How can I find yout where it is located?

Comment: is your phone rooted?

Comment: First you need to be rooted. Then you if you don't find you can search in: /data/app/com.yourpackage.yourapp/databases/yourdatabasename.db

Answer (score 4):

The acutal path is `/data/data/package.name/database`.
If your app is in debug mode, most newer devices allow accessing this folder via Android Studio (or adb run-as). On the emulator this folder is public.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the command in terminal

```
adb pull /data/data/com.example.myapplication/databases/your_db.db
```

Comment: This will work on Rooted devices that to debug apks and rooted devices (Release and debug). Make sure app is debuggable or not

Answer (score 0):

No need to root your device.

**I used this way on Mac with Terminal:**

```
sudo adb -d shell "run-as com.YOUR_COMPANY.YOUR_APP_NAME cat databases/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME.db" > NEW_NAME_FOR_DATABASE.sqlite
```

Sometimes you need first to give that file a permission 666, so you can copy it to your computer.

```
chmod 666 YOUR_DATABASE_NAME.db
```

Answer (score -1):

Your device must be **Rootable**  for you to be able to see the **.DB** file

Comment: Does it has to be rooted or does it has to be rootable?

Answer (score -1):

for the second question, try to search for your package name first. Maybe it's like xxx.xxx.Christina.xxx.AppName ?